# Why decode using base64 not working correctly in C#

Tags: c#, base64, decode, encode

I have two methods "EncodePassword" and "DecodePassword" as the following:

```
// Pass the password as a string, then return the encoded password
string EncodePassword(string password)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
}

// Pass the encoded password, then return that as a string
string DecodePassword(string password)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(password));
}
```

The EncodePassword method works perfectly, but DecodePassword method don't!
So for example when I try to encode "testpassword", the result is "dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk", but when I try to decode "dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk", the result is some of question marks like this "��-��,�".
So what is the problem please?

Comment: When I try the code, it works just fine. How do you call the methods?

Comment: Thanks Guffa, the problem solved after restarted Visual Studio and Google Chrome (because I worked in asp.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code works as expected. there must be a problem with loading the string in the first place - or you mess up encoding when processing the generated string.

```
[TestMethod]
public void EncodeAndDecodePwd()
{
  const string pwd = "testpassword";
  string encodedPassword = EncodePassword(pwd);
  string decodedPassword = DecodePassword(encodedPassword);
  string decodedPassword2 = DecodePassword("dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk");
  Assert.AreEqual(pwd, decodedPassword);
  Assert.AreEqual(pwd, decodedPassword2);
  Assert.AreEqual(encodedPassword, "dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk");
}
```

BR

Comment: just for completeness add the Assert.AreEqual(encodedPassword, "dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk");